# Import error in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, resolve

> jp.co.wap.exam.lib.Interval can not be resolve

I am trying to define an interval like this:

```
Interval interval1 = new Interval ("08:00"."09:00");
```

It's giving the error `Interval can not be resolve`. I am using Eclipse. I hover the cursor over the `Interval` text but there is not option for import. How can I resolve the import problem?

Comment: add the library to build path

Comment: Go to project tab and select clean project after added the library to your claspath.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the library (a jar file) in the classpath.

In eclipse, select your project folder and go to navigation bar:
`Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External JARs` (or `Add JARs`, depending on where your jar file is).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Jar containing the Interval class is not on the class path.